# Whats the best way to phrase this? "Gary Payton tells Marcus Smart that he reminds him of himself"

Tags: pronouns

Is "he reminds him of himself" correct usage of pronouns in this case?

Comment: Needs context!!

Comment: When you ask “What’s the best way to phrase this?” you are implying that there is something wrong with the way it’s already phrased. When you give us some context, please give us your opinion of this phrase as it stands.

Comment: To avoid an ambiguity you could say that Marcus reminds Gary of himself, and Gary tells him so. But in the particular example the ambiguity seems far-fetched; how could Gary be telling Marcus what Gary reminds Marcus of? Marcus would know this better than Gary would.

Comment: The sentence is set up to make the reader work too hard. Have mercy. There's only one way to puzzle it out, but it's messy.

Comment: This is the context:  https://nesn.com/2020/01/this-nba-hall-of-famer-says-celtics-marcus-smart-reminds-him-of-himself/  So I would have phrased it, “Gary Payton tells Marcus Smart, ‘You remind me of myself’.”

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a valid grammatical sentence and is possible in ordinary usage but it is not the best way to phrase the sentence since the reader has to work hard to establish who the “him” and the “himself” actually refer to.

The sentence might have been better phrased as follows as it is much clearer who the “me” and “myself” refer to,

> Gary Payton tells Marcus Smart, “You remind me of myself.”

As this is a headline and perhaps a design/style decision was made not to use the quote in this way.